# JavaScript Global Variables

Tags: javascript

```
var channelsArray = [];
var percentArray= [];
var valueArray= [];
var jsonData,canvas,context;
var colorArray=["#ECD078","#D95B43","#C02942","#542437","#53777A"];
var posX=220;
var posY=60;
var width=55;
var graph=false;


//Webservice Request and Response begins....................................... 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/WebSite1/myservice.asmx/GetData",
            dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function(msg) {
        if(localStorage.getItem("channels")==null){
                  jsonData =jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                  jsonToLocal();        
             }     
                 var strDisplay = " <table cellspacing='0' id='myTable' " +
                                 " <tr>" +
                                 " <th > Channels </th>" +
                                 " <th> Percentage</th>" +
                                 " <th> Value</th>" +
                                 " </tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
                    strDisplay = strDisplay +
                                 " <tr style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='javascript:rotateChart("+i+")'>" +
                                 " <td>" + channelsArray[i] + "</a> </td>" +
                                 " <td> " + percentArray[i] + " </td>" +
                                 " <td> " + valueArray[i] + " </td>" +

                                 " </tr>";

                }
                strDisplay = strDisplay + "</table>";

                document.getElementById('DynamicGridLoading').innerHTML = strDisplay;
                  document.getElementById('myTable').setAttribute("class","datatable");


            },


             error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
             alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });

//Webservice Request and Response ends........................

//converting json data into local storage....

function jsonToLocal(){




            for(i=0;i<jsonData.Table.length;i++){

               percentArray.push(jsonData.Table[i].toString());
               channelsArray.push(jsonData.Table[i].Channels);
               valueArray.push(jsonData.Table[i].Value);
            }


            try {
                    localStorage.setItem("percentage", percentArray.join(",")); 
                    localStorage.setItem("channels",channelsArray .join(","));
                    localStorage.setItem("value",valueArray.join(","));



                }
            catch (e) {
                            if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                                 alert("Quota exceeded!");
                             }
                      }

}
```

this is my almost entire code...am getting this 'uncaught' error in function jsontolocal at percentArray....if i remove this line..other two work fine.. all these arrays are pushing string values inside dem..

Comment: You should use `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: **Show us some real code** - In your example the function is never called since you made a typo in the function call!

Comment: hey ThiefMaster..thnx..but there's no typo in the actual code. (sorry for my typing mistake :) )

Comment: Well your actual code has some other problem. You cannot show us a testcase that works perfectly fine (escept the typo)...

Comment: try: "[]" inplace of "new Array()", or show some more codes

Comment: `[]` is completely equal to `new Array()`

Comment: also check your dependent files that you have referenced actually gets downloaded, you may use firebug to see that. File referencing usually gives error in asp.net because of poor practices done by developers.

Comment: Given that you've typed the code and not pasted, I am given to believe that this is not an accurate reflection of your actual source. Can I suggest you edit the question and paste your code in, including these other 'three arrays'. You'll also need to code-format the code in the question, by highlighting it and clicking the '{}' button

Comment: hey i have submitted my entire code..please see where's the error..

Comment: Proper code formatting would help too.

Comment: It doesn't look like this code contains the problem.  Your referencing is fine - and `percentArray` is used identically to `channelsArray` and `valueArray` in what you've posted.  If the latter two arrays work, the former should as well.  Try looking for somewhere that `percentArray` is handled differently to the other two - or alternative, remove layers of complexity until it starts working, then add them back until it stops, and you'll soon findt he culprit.

Comment: hello everyone...as i had said earlier..this entire code works fine wen i fire it thru visual studio...am still getting random variables null error wen i fire it through iis...but now..it works..specially wen i try to debug it through firebug..strange but that's truth.. if you ever come to knw this strange behavior of variables in the browser..please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was nothing but random and unknown behavior of javascript.. To ensure that this never happens..i found out to follow following things while writing a javascript code -:

1. use === to compare with a null value and 0
2. provide radix while using parseInt..ie..parseInt(string,radix);
3. always declare variables like for(var i=0;...and not for(i=0;........

these were the mistakes i was making..sometimes it would run..sometimes it would show a random behavior..anyways..my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo :

```
 myfucntion()
```

should be

```
 myfunction();
```

this code works (i put the function call beneath the function because otherwise in the global scope (i tested it in firebug console) the function wasn't recognized):

```
var myArray=[];


function myfunction(){

   myArray.push('s');   //at this point..my global array is not recognized.

}
myfunction();


alert(myArray[0]);//alert s
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GrpJw/1/

Comment: That's not the reason for his problem though. According to his error message `push()` is called but on a `null` value and not an array

Comment: between the declaration and the function call..am doing an $(ajax) post...and i call this myfunction() inside success:function(msg){}, does it affect the declaration scope in any way??